# Duplicate identifier/duplicate string index signature with code on a mounted drive

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript2.0, tsconfig

My typescript project resides in c:\data.
c:\data maps to f: via a mounted drive :

[image: mounted drive]

I use Visual Studio 2015, Typescript Tools 2.0.5 with npm Typescript@2.1.5

Typescript in visual studio somehow picks up both/two paths pointing to the same  d.ts typing files, e.g. C:\data\xpsdev\trunk\web\workforce.mvc\node_modules\@types\jquery\index.d.ts 
AND 
F:\xpsdev\trunk\web\workforce.mvc\node_modules\@types\jquery\index.d.ts

resulting in duplicate identifier/signature errors in the error list..

[image: error list]

[image: file ref 1]
[image: file ref 2]

How can I avoid Visual studio not to take into account both paths ???

Excluding "f:\xpsdev" in tsconfig did not work...

Answer (score 0):

The solution was adding

`{ compileroptions : {"watch": true } }`

I get a new error "The current host does not support the --watch option" because tsc.exe does not support watching as node.js does

cfr https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2375

But I can just ignore this.